# Is redshift possible if relative speed is 0?

Tags: visible-light, doppler-effect

Since we are in a galaxy that is moving 1M mph, and the speed of light is constant, is redshift affected by whether you are facing toward or away from the direction the galaxy is moving?

Suppose you are in a line between two light sources, A and B. You are all in line with the direction the galaxy is traveling and A is in the lead, so to speak. You are all traveling the same speed, 1M mph, so there is no relative speed between you.

If you measure the redshift from the light sources, would it be neutral? Or would A be blue shifted, and B be redshifted, since you are moving upstream to A and downstream to B? Or does it depend entirely on the relative speed of the two objects?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm sure it has to be a function of relative speed, and therefore would be neutral in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would experience no redshift, ignoring gravity and the expansion of space.